# como obtener llave de un valor que obtengo previamente en firebase database?

Tags: java, firebase

Actualmente estoy ingresando un objeto tipo hash map  a realmtime database en este método:

```
private void guardarActividad() {
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("actividades");
    String keyId = myRef.push().getKey();
    Map<String, Object> actividades = new HashMap<>();
    actividades.put("usuario", tvUser.getText().toString());
    actividades.put("nombreActividad", etNombreA.getText().toString());
    actividades.put("tipoActividad", spTipoA.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
    actividades.put("fechaAvance", tvFecha.getText().toString());
    actividades.put("valorAvance", etValorA.getText().toString());
    actividades.put("idKey",keyId);
    //actividades.put("valorAvance", tvValorA);


    myRef.child(keyId).setValue(actividades);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Se guardó la actividad..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Y estoy llenando un spinner con el nombreActividad de todos los registros para escoger uno de esos valores posteriormente en un formulario y enviarlos a otro objeto en la realtime database de firebase así debería quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que cuando seleccione en el spinner un nombreActividad y guarde ese formulario, también me debe guardar un campo con la llave del documento donde se encuentra ese nombreActividad.

```
private void rellenarSpinnerActividades() {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference fDatabaseRoot = database.getReference().child("actividades");

fDatabaseRoot.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        final List<String> propertyAddressList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot addressSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String propertyAddress = addressSnapshot.child("nombreActividad").getValue(String.class);

            if (propertyAddress!=null ){
                propertyAddressList.add(propertyAddress);

            }


        }

        Spinner spinnerProperty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> addressAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, propertyAddressList);
        addressAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProperty.setAdapter(addressAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

}

Estoy intentando traer la llave de ese documento así pero no logro hacerlo...
Agradezco cualquier información que sirva de ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay una cosa que no entiendo, dentro de actividades tenes todas las actividades con un key unico, y dentro de esa actividad tenes otro campo que se llama idKey, ese campo es el que necesitas para decirle al nuevo form que pertenezca a esa key no ? Si es asi, por que no guardas el idKey como el key de la actividad en si ? luego con getKey() podes obtener esa llave mas facil. Si lo guardas asi, dejarias como tenes la query para traer todos los nombres y luego usas getKey() para obtener la key que le corresponde a cada nombre de actividad

Comment: @GastónSaillén gracias por responder, según entiendo estoy llamando bien el nombreActividad pero no comprendo de que manera obtengo el key luego de seleccionar el nombreActividad en el spinner?  te agradezco cualquier comentario o recomendacion!

Answer (score 0):

Tenes dos opciones.

1. La primera es guardar ese `idKey` como la key principal de la actividad, entonces podes llamar `getKey()` en cada elemento de `nombreActividad` y te va a devolver la key de cada uno.
2. Crear un objeto del tipo Actividad y dentro del for que solicitas los datos, guardar todos los datos de la actividad en un objeto dentro de la lista.

Recorda que propertyAddress va a ser de tipo Actividad

```
final List<Actividad> propertyAddressList = new ArrayList<Actividad>();

    for (DataSnapshot addressSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Actividad actividad = addressSnapshot.getValue(Actividad.class);
                    String idKey = actividad.getIdKey();
                    String nombreActividad = actividad.getNombreActividad();
                    actividad.setIdKey(idKey)
                    actividad.setNombreActividad(nombreActividad);

                    if (propertyAddress!=null ){
                        propertyAddressList.add(actividad);
                    }
                }
```

Entonces, luego de guardarlo en una lista de este tipo, modificas el adaptador del spinner y vas a poder acceder a todas las propiedades de cada elemento de la lista, tanto su idKey, como su nombre, como todos los campos que setees en el objeto Actividad.

Recorda, que algo muy importante al usar una API asyncrona, es nunca esquivar los errores

```
 @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      Log.e("Error al solicitar los datos: ", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```